# MapView in not moving always animate to the user current location

Tags: android

I am developing an app which finds user current location and find near by places also.I have almost completed the app,but now the problem is that when user current location is find and a marker is added to user current location, but when i want to move or scroll the map to any other location in the onTouchEvent method map is not moving and and get back to the user current location marker.In emulator onTouchEvnet working fine but on device it is not working here is my code for moving map.

//here is my code for moving map

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
      if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
             GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
             (int) event.getX(),
             (int) event.getY());
             MapController mc=mapView.getController();
             mc.animateTo(p);
             return true;
       } else{
             return false;
       }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you trying to animate to a specific location when the user touches that point but it is just going back to the users current location? This is probably because MyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation() tries to keep the blue dot visible in the MapView.